# Auxiliary channel signals in display port

Tags: displayport

Can anyone tell me the significance or functionality of auxiliary channel(P and N) in display port interface.

Answer (score 0):

Most important functionality of the auxiliary channel is to exchange information so that the PC can read and identify the display and the resolutions it supports in order to select or limit the resolution selection to include only formats that the display is capable of displaying.